# How to post immediately after svg to canvas conversion is done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, svg, html2canvas

I am attempting post with html2canvas after converting all the svgs in a html element to canvas, but the post executes immediately before the svg to canvas conversion finishes, since it takes a few seconds. I have tried using deferred and promises, but I am still having the same issue.

```
    // https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/95#issuecomment-45114424
    // First render all SVGs to canvases
    targetElem = $('#dashboard');

    var elements = targetElem.find('svg').map(function() {
        var svg = $(this);
        var canvas = $('<canvas></canvas>');
        svg.replaceWith(canvas);

        // Get the raw SVG string and curate it
        var content = svg.wrap('<p></p>').parent().html();
        content = content.replace(/xlink:title='hide\/show'/g, '');
        content = encodeURIComponent(content);
        svg.unwrap();

        // Create an image from the svg
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + content;
        image.onload = function() {
            canvas[0].width = image.width;
            canvas[0].height = image.height;

            // Render the image to the canvas
            var context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
            context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        };

        return {
            svg: svg,
            canvas: canvas
        };
    }); // end of targetElem.find('svg').map(function() {...});
```

**EDITED**: Here is the deferred and promise I have been attempting to implement to create two operations that run in sequential order.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $( '#save_dashboard' ).click(function() {

    // Create a deferred object
    var dfd = $.Deferred();

        // https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/95#issuecomment-45114424
        // First render all SVGs to canvases
        targetElem = $('#dashboard');

        var elements = targetElem.find('svg').map(function() {
            var svg = $(this);
            var canvas = $('<canvas></canvas>');
            svg.replaceWith(canvas);

            // Get the raw SVG string and curate it
            var content = svg.wrap('<p></p>').parent().html();
            content = content.replace(/xlink:title='hide\/show'/g, '');
            content = encodeURIComponent(content);
            svg.unwrap();

            // Create an image from the svg
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + content;
            image.onload = function() {
                canvas[0].width = image.width;
                canvas[0].height = image.height;

                // Render the image to the canvas
                var context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
                context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
            };
            dfd.resolve();

            return dfd.promise();
            };
        }); // end of targetElem.find('svg').map(function() {...});

        dfd.resolve();

        $.when(dfd).done(function(){
            console.log('dfd done');

            // http://www.kubilayerdogan.net/html2canvas-take-screenshot-of-web-page-and-save-it-to-server-javascript-and-php/
            $('#dashboard').html2canvas({
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    //Set hidden field's value to image data (base-64 string)
                    var dashboardPng = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                    console.log('dashboardPng: ' + dashboardPng);

                    $.ajax({
                        url:'save_dashboard_image.php',
                        data:{dashboardPngData: dashboardPng},
                        type:'POST',
                        dataType:'json',
                        success: function(){
                            console.log('success');
                        }
                        ,
                        error: function(xhr, status, error){
                            console.log('The requested page was: ' + document.URL +
                                '. The error number returned was: ' + xhr.status +
                                '. The error message was: ' + error);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }); // end of $.when(dfd).done(...)
    }); // end of save_dashboard click function
}); // end of document ready
```

Comment: Can include `html` ,  "post" `js`  _"I am attempting run post after converting svgs to canvas, but the post executes immediately before the conversion finishes"_ ? Is expected return value of `elements` jQuery object , or `array` ? Can create stacksnippets http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: The code is async so you need to use callback/promises. You said you tried with promise, could you show the code for this?

Comment: @Ken Fyrstenberg I have  updated with the promises that I tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated

Note, Untested. Adjusted `click` event to return multiple `canvas` , promise objects , to `.then()`

If interpret question correctly, try

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $( '#save_dashboard' ).click(function() {

    // Create a deferred object
    // dfd = new $.Deferred();

        // https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/95#issuecomment-45114424
        // First render all SVGs to canvases
        targetElem = $('#dashboard');
        var promises = $.when.apply(targetElem, $.map(targetElem.find('svg')
          , function(el, index) {
            return new $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
              var svg = $(el);
              var canvas = $('<canvas></canvas>');
              svg.replaceWith(canvas);

              // Get the raw SVG string and curate it
              var content = svg.wrap('<p></p>').parent().html();
              content = content.replace(/xlink:title='hide\/show'/g, '');
              content = encodeURIComponent(content);
              svg.unwrap();

              // Create an image from the svg
              var image = new Image();

              image.onload = function() {
                  canvas[0].width = image.width;
                  canvas[0].height = image.height;

                  // Render the image to the canvas
                  var context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');

                  dfd.resolve(context.drawImage(image, 0, 0));
              };
              image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + content;
            }).promise();          
          })
         ); // end of targetElem.find('svg').map(function() {...});



        promises.then(function(_canvas) {
            console.log('dfd done', _canvas, arguments);

            // http://www.kubilayerdogan.net/html2canvas-take-screenshot-of-web-page-and-save-it-to-server-javascript-and-php/
            $('#dashboard').html2canvas({
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    //Set hidden field's value to image data (base-64 string)
                    var dashboardPng = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                    console.log('dashboardPng: ' + dashboardPng);

                    $.ajax({
                        url:'save_dashboard_image.php',
                        data:{dashboardPngData: dashboardPng},
                        type:'POST',
                        dataType:'json',
                        success: function(){
                            console.log('success');
                        }
                        ,
                        error: function(xhr, status, error){
                            console.log('The requested page was: ' + document.URL +
                                '. The error number returned was: ' + xhr.status +
                                '. The error message was: ' + error);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }); // end of $.when(dfd).done(...)
    }); // end of save_dashboard click function
}); // end of document
```

Comment: So it works with your implementation. Looks like I need to pass what is being resolved instead. Is there a reason you use _canvas in dfd.then(function(_canvas) {
            console.log('dfd done', _canvas);
I guess in this case deferred.then can be used here, since deferred.then executes immediately, but will not be resolved until the drawImage() is done.

Comment: Seems that the resolve if fired after converting the first svg to canvas and post catches only the first svg at that point. How can I resolve the entire conversion process?

Comment: @user2120512  _"Is there a reason you use _canvas in dfd.then(function(_canvas) { console.log('dfd done', _canvas);"_   Did / do not have stacksnippets / jsfiddle of actual implementation - including `html` . Was not certain if return `promise` value from `elements` loop would / could be utilized at `.then()` .

Comment: @user2120512 Should `$('#dashboard').html2canvas({})` be called for each of the returned promise values ?

Comment: Yes, each would make better sense than map.

Comment: @user2120512 Not certain interpret _"each would make better sense than map"_ correctly ?, within `.then()` at `$('#dashboard').html2canvas({})` ? Tried updated post ?

Comment: Interestingly .then() works,  but not with done(). I would think that done() would always be better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75337/discussion-between-guest271314-and-user2120512).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** I had to use an array for each successive svg to canvas conversion and when they were all complete. I could pass the array to then() to post the html2canvas.

1. Create a new array on click, use that to store all deferreds from SVGs
2. Loop through all SVG elements

   - In each instance, create a new internal deferred object
   - Resolve or reject the deferred
   - Push it into the array outside the loop
3. Use `$.when.apply($, arrayOfDeferredObjects)` to check for status of all deferred objects in the array

   ```
   $( '#save_dashboard' ).click(function() {

       // Declare an array to store all deferred objects from each svg element
       var svgDfds = [],
           targetElem = $('#dashboard');

       targetElem.find('svg').each(function() {
           var dfd = new $.Deferred(),
               svg = $(this),
               canvas = $('<canvas></canvas>');

           svg.replaceWith(canvas);

           // Get the raw SVG string and curate it
           var content = svg.wrap('<p></p>').parent().html();
           content = content.replace(/xlink:title='hide\/show'/g, '');
           content = encodeURIComponent(content);
           svg.unwrap();

           // Create an image from the svg
           var image = new Image();
           image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + content;
           image.onload = function() {
               canvas[0].width = image.width;
               canvas[0].height = image.height;

               // Render the image to the canvas
               var context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');

               // Resolve or reject the deferred
               dfd.resolve(context.drawImage(image, 0, 0));
           };

           // Push deferred object into array
           svgDfds.push(dfd);

       }); // end of targetElem.find('svg').map(function() {...});

       // Check for all deferreds
       $.when.apply($, svgDfds).then(function(_canvas) {
           console.log('dfd done', _canvas);

           // http://www.kubilayerdogan.net/html2canvas-take-screenshot-of-web-page-and-save-it-to-server-javascript-and-php/
           $('#dashboard').html2canvas({
               onrendered: function (canvas) {
                   //Set hidden field's value to image data (base-64 string)
                   var dashboardPng = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                   console.log('dashboardPng: ' + dashboardPng);

                   $.ajax({
                       url:'save_dashboard_image.php',
                       data:{dashboardPngData: dashboardPng},
                       type:'POST',
                       dataType:'json',
                       success: function(){
                           console.log('success');
                       }
                       ,
                       error: function(xhr, status, error){
                           console.log('The requested page was: ' + document.URL +
                               '. The error number returned was: ' + xhr.status +
                               '. The error message was: ' + error);
                       }
                   });
               }
           });
       });

   }); // end of save_dashboard click function
   ```

Comment: Can describe difference between this solution , solution at updated post, above ?

Comment: I have updated the difference between the solution that I found with your help.