# Move deferred.resolve from an operation inside a function to the entire function completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, svg, html2canvas

When I move deferred.resolve to outside after the all the svg to canvas, I am not getting the entire function to work inside a deferred.resolve. I want the deferred.promise() to execute when all the svgs are converted to canvas and not just the first svg.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $( '#save_dashboard' ).click(function() {

        // Create a deferred object
        var dfd = new $.Deferred();

        // https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/95#issuecomment-45114424
        // First render all SVGs to canvases
        targetElem = $('#dashboard');

        var elements = targetElem.find('svg').map(function() {
            var svg = $(this);
            var canvas = $('<canvas></canvas>');
            svg.replaceWith(canvas);

            // Get the raw SVG string and curate it
            var content = svg.wrap('<p></p>').parent().html();
            content = content.replace(/xlink:title='hide\/show'/g, '');
            content = encodeURIComponent(content);
            svg.unwrap();

            // Create an image from the svg
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + content;
            image.onload = function() {
                canvas[0].width = image.width;
                canvas[0].height = image.height;

                // Render the image to the canvas
                var context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
                dfd.resolve(context.drawImage(image, 0, 0));
            };

            return dfd.promise();
            /* return {
                svg: svg,
                canvas: canvas
            }; */
        }); // end of targetElem.find('svg').map(function() {...});

        // $.when(dfd).done(function(){
        //    console.log('dfd done');
        dfd.then(function(_canvas){
            console.log('dfd done', _canvas);

            // http://www.kubilayerdogan.net/html2canvas-take-screenshot-of-web-page-and-save-it-to-server-javascript-and-php/
            $('#dashboard').html2canvas({
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    //Set hidden field's value to image data (base-64 string)
                    var dashboardPng = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                    console.log('dashboardPng: ' + dashboardPng);

                    $.ajax({
                        url:'save_dashboard_image.php',
                        data:{dashboardPngData: dashboardPng},
                        type:'POST',
                        dataType:'json',
                        success: function(){
                            console.log('success');
                        }
                        ,
                        error: function(xhr, status, error){
                            console.log('The requested page was: ' + document.URL +
                                '. The error number returned was: ' + xhr.status +
                                '. The error message was: ' + error);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        // }); // end of when(dfd).done()
        }); // end of dfd.then(function(_canvas){...})

    }); // end of save_dashboard click function
}); // end of document ready
```

**Solution** Modified from Terry's answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29637380/2120512

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $( '#save_dashboard' ).click(function() {

        // Declare an array to store all deferred objects from each svg element
        var svgDfds = [],
            targetElem = $('#dashboard');

        targetElem.find('svg').each(function() {
            var dfd = new $.Deferred(),
                svg = $(this),
                canvas = $('<canvas></canvas>');

            svg.replaceWith(canvas);

            // Get the raw SVG string and curate it
            var content = svg.wrap('<p></p>').parent().html();
            content = content.replace(/xlink:title='hide\/show'/g, '');
            content = encodeURIComponent(content);
            svg.unwrap();

            // Create an image from the svg
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + content;
            image.onload = function() {
                canvas[0].width = image.width;
                canvas[0].height = image.height;

                // Render the image to the canvas
                var context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');

                // Resolve or reject the deferred
                dfd.resolve(context.drawImage(image, 0, 0));
            };

            // Push deferred object into array
            svgDfds.push(dfd);

        }); // end of targetElem.find('svg').map(function() {...});

        // Check for all deferreds
        $.when.apply($, svgDfds).then(function(_canvas) {
            console.log('dfd done', _canvas);

            // http://www.kubilayerdogan.net/html2canvas-take-screenshot-of-web-page-and-save-it-to-server-javascript-and-php/
            $('#dashboard').html2canvas({
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    //Set hidden field's value to image data (base-64 string)
                    var dashboardPng = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                    console.log('dashboardPng: ' + dashboardPng);

                    $.ajax({
                        url:'save_dashboard_image.php',
                        data:{dashboardPngData: dashboardPng},
                        type:'POST',
                        dataType:'json',
                        success: function(){
                            console.log('success');
                        }
                        ,
                        error: function(xhr, status, error){
                            console.log('The requested page was: ' + document.URL +
                                '. The error number returned was: ' + xhr.status +
                                '. The error message was: ' + error);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });

    }); // end of save_dashboard click function
}); // end of document ready
```

Comment: duplicate of [How to post immediately after svg to canvas conversion is done?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29635005/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should structure your code in the following way:

1. Create a new array on click, use that to store all deferreds from SVGs
2. Loop through all SVG elements

   - In each instance, create a new internal deferred object
   - Resolve or reject the deferred
   - Push it into the array outside the loop
3. Use `$.when.apply($, arrayOfDeferredObjects)` to check for status of all deferred objects in the array

In code, that should look like this:

```
$('#save_dashboard').click(function() {

    var svgDfd = [],  // Declare an array to store ALL deferreds from svgs
        $targetElem = $('#dashboard');

    // Use .each() to iterate through all SVGs
    $targetElem.find('svg').each(function() {

        // New deferred object per SVG instance
        var dfd = new $.Deferred();

        // At some point in your code, resolve or reject the deferred
        dfd.resolve();

        // Push deferred object into array
        svgDfds.push(dfd);
    }

    // Check for all deferreds
    $.when.apply($, svgDfds).then(function() {
        // Do stuff
    });
});
```

Therefore, with your code slightly modified and refactored to fit the paradigm above:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $( '#save_dashboard' ).click(function() {

        // Declare an array to store all deferredo objects from each svg element
        var svgDfds = [],
            $targetElem = $('#dashboard');

        $targetElem.find('svg').each(function() {
            var dfd = new $.Deferred(),
                svg = $(this),
                canvas = $('<canvas></canvas>');

            svg.replaceWith(canvas);

            // Get the raw SVG string and curate it
            var content = svg.wrap('<p></p>').parent().html();
            content = content.replace(/xlink:title='hide\/show'/g, '');
            content = encodeURIComponent(content);
            svg.unwrap();

            // Create an image from the svg
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + content;
            image.onload = function() {
                canvas[0].width = image.width;
                canvas[0].height = image.height;

                // Render the image to the canvas
                var context = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
                dfd.resolve(context.drawImage(image, 0, 0));
            };

            svgDfds.push(dfd);

        });


        $.when.apply($, svgDfds).then(function(){
            $('#dashboard').html2canvas({
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    //Set hidden field's value to image data (base-64 string)
                    var dashboardPng = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                    console.log('dashboardPng: ' + dashboardPng);

                    $.ajax({
                        url:'save_dashboard_image.php',
                        data:{dashboardPngData: dashboardPng},
                        type:'POST',
                        dataType:'json',
                        success: function(){
                            console.log('success');
                        }
                        ,
                        error: function(xhr, status, error){
                            console.log('The requested page was: ' + document.URL +
                                '. The error number returned was: ' + xhr.status +
                                '. The error message was: ' + error);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: Just discovered apply() to call an array of arguments. Mind blown! This helps solve the problem of iterating through each svg element and posting the finished converted canvas.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a single deferred for multiple image loads. Each image does need its own deferred, so that you can create a dedicated promise for it. Only then you get back an array of different promises (that each resolve when their respective image is loaded), which you then can [pass all to `$.when`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5627284/1048572) to await them.

Your code should look like this:

```
$( '#save_dashboard' ).click(function() {
    var targetElem = $('#dashboard');

    var elementPromises = targetElem.find('svg').map(function() {
        // Create the deferred objects here!
        var dfd = new $.Deferred();
        …
        var image = new Image();
        …
        image.onload = function() {
            …
            dfd.resolve(context.drawImage(image, 0, 0));
        };

        return dfd.promise();
    }).get(); // an array, not a jquery collection

    var allLoaded = $.when.apply($, elementPromises);
    allLoaded.then(…);
});
```

Comment: my svgs convert, but post doesn't catch the newly created canvases from the svgs on the page. It executes before the canvases are finished being created.

Comment: That's odd. The canvas are created and inserted into the page synchronously, and `allLoaded` doesn't resolve before all pictures are drawn on them.

Comment: Without deferred I was able to do this in a two-step process too: convert the svgs to canvases, and post the screen capture with html2canvas.

Comment: It still is that two-step process? I wonder how you did the parallel async svg conversion without promises.

Comment: It was a broken two-step process. I attempted to convert and the post would immediately execute. If I reattempted with the newly converted canvases, it would post the obviously have the correct canvases. Terry's solution is working with a little modification. Thank you Bergi!

Comment: @user2120512: Well, it was basically the same solution as mine. What did you need to modify?